# Excel VLookup issue with returning incorrect lookup results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am running into some issues with my two vlookup formulas, which are searching for words in a second sheet, then returning a yes or no into the columns.

On sheet 1 there are names and demographic info, then on sheet 2, there is demographic info, and also lists whether or not the person has signed two different forms

So here are the two formulas that I am using:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("team",VLOOKUP($A2,Forms!$A$2:$B$300,2,FALSE))>0,"yes","no"),"no")
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("honey",VLOOKUP($A2,Forms!$A$2:$B$300,2,FALSE))>0,"yes","no"),"no")
```

So my problem that I am having is that for the "team" lookup formula, it's returning a 'yes' for most records, but there are some records that its returning a 'no' when it should be 'yes', and for the "honey" formula, its doing the opposite, its returning mainly 'no' when they should be 'yes' and only returning 'yes' a couple of times.

Here is what each sheet looks like:

sheet 1

```
Name, member number, phone, email, team form, honey form
Adam B, 1234, 123-111-1231, a@aol.com, yes, no
Bob A, 1235, 123-111-1234, b@aol.com. yes, no
Rachel C, 1236, 123-123-1234, r@aol.com, no, yes
Tim F, 1237, 123-123-2345, t@aol.com, no, no
...
```

Sheet 2 (Forms)

```
Name, signed forms
Adam B, Uploaded TEAM Liability Form
Adam B, Uploaded Honey Run Liability Form
Bob A, Uploaded TEAM Liability Form
Bob A, Uploaded Honey Run Form
Rachel C, Uploaded TEAM Liability Form
Rachel C, Uploaded Honey Run Liability Form
Tim F, Uploaded Honey Run Liability Form
...
```

So as you can see from the sample of the data in each sheet, the formula should be matching that text all of the time, but I am not sure why its not, and need some assistance with this.

I have also tried changing which column its trying to match for instance instead of name, i tried matching by 'member number' so I would add that column to the Forms sheet, but no change.  I tried changing the search text in formula 2 from 'honey' to 'liability' and then the formula worked perfectly, but not sure why the 'team' and 'honey' words are causing the formula not to work correctly all the time.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The reason is that VLOOKUP always returns the first found value where it meets the search condition. If you want to search for all results from a condition, look into FILTER, or if you have older Excel search on here for combinations of INDEX and AGGREGATE

Comment: I understand that, but if it finds a record, like in my example above the formula looking for 'team' should have returned a yes for Rachel, as this was the 1st result from the condition it was looking for to match Rachel C.  Isn't that a correct statement?  I have Office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multi-Lookup Using `MAKEARRAY` With `INDEX` and `SEARCH`

[image]

```
=LET(sn,Forms!A2:A8,sf,Forms!B2:B8,dn,A2:A5,
    t,"Team",h,"Honey",y,"Yes",n,"No",
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(dn),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
    IF(SUM((sn=INDEX(dn,r))*(ISNUMBER(
        SEARCH("*"&IF(c=1,t,h)&"*",sf))))>0,y,n))))
```

- If you don't have Microsoft 365, the following formula in cell `E2` might work:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Forms!$A$2:$A$8=$A2)*(ISNUMBER(
    SEARCH("*"&CHOOSE(MOD(COLUMN(E$1),2)+1,"Honey","Team")
        &"*",Forms!$B$2:$B$8))))>0,"Yes","No")
```

Copy across.

- Note that the result of `CHOOSE` depends on the 1st column, column `E`, being an odd column.

Comment: Thank you, but I do have Microsoft 365, but the make array isn't working, and when I increase the range of the formula to work, it just keeps giving me errors, in sheet1 the a column has records up to 250, and in the Forms sheet, has 217 rows currently, but these reports are dynamic and change

Comment: Thank you, I played around with this form some more and it did the trick, thank you.